# Blockquote HTML in Markdown stops unordered lists from working

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, markdown, blockquote

Though it's consistent between the preview and the rendered version in the post the `<blockquote>` HTML tag is inconsistent with the Markdown shorthand `>` prefix.

Here's a sample:

```
<blockquote>

 - item 1
 - item 2

</blockquote>
```

incorrectly produces:

> - item 1
>  - item 2

Whereas:

```
> - item 1
> - item 2
```

correctly produces:

> - item 1
> - item 2

Comment: This has been reported several times before, and each time it gets slapped with a [status-I-don't-think-it's-important-enough-to-fix] tag.

Comment: @Ether, these are blockquotes, not code blocks. worth fixing or not it's still a bug that didn't appear when I searched for it, hence the new post.

Comment: @ether are you sure those are related? I don't think they are. (in fact I am sure of it, so I am removing the "related" entries)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kenny is right -- the [Markdown spec](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax) says...

> Note that Markdown formatting syntax is not processed within block-level HTML tags. E.g., you can’t use Markdown-style *emphasis* inside an HTML block.

And `<blockquote>` is, as its name implies, a **block** element...

Answer (score 3):

> It seems that
>
> ---
>
> All **markdowns** are *disabled* within a `<blockquote>`

```
*Almost* like

 - how a `<pre>` tag works.
```

#### and that *also* include

`other paragraph-level tags.`

1. * such as
   * <h*N*>, <ol>, and <p> tags
2. I don't know if it's a bug or [status-bydesign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/status-bydesign).
3. Since you're supposed to use **H<sup>T</sup>M<sub>L</sub>** in HTML tags??